# use two templateobject on one page based on condition

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I have two template object of templavoila

1: old version

2: new version

Now I need ona one page (uid = 35) use them both. I mean that for all records except `B` I need to use `old version` and for record `B` I need to use `new version`

Can I somehow using typoscript overrun setting set in Apperance tab